# Is there any point to collecting more blocks than needed for a level?

Tags: blocks-that-matter

I've just started playing Blocks That Matter, and I'm wondering if there's any point in attempting to collect more blocks than needed to meet the quota. I kind of feel this compulsive need to collect things in case I'm going to miss something and also for completionist's sake, but if I don't gain anything from it, I don't want to waste my time.

Are there any achievements or gameplay advantages related to collecting all the blocks in a level, or should I just try to control my OCD impulses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the levels also have a star you can earn for entering the portal with a certain amount of blocks or more. The star will appear in the lower right of the screen when you have collected the locked chest for the level. This will light up when the limit is reached.

Note: You do not need the chest to earn the star, but you don't know the limit without it.

Comment: I'm on `Wood, Stone, and Sand`, and I've collected all the blocks in this level as well as the chest, yet I see no star in the bottom right, or anywhere for that matter. Am I doing something wrong? Also, with not needing to have the chest to earn the star, does that mean you can earn the star without having the chest if you have enough blocks?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Yes you don't need the chest to get the star, only to get the indicator.